# Little work left; a French female is propitious

Tags: cryptic-clues

Can anyone explain how the cryptic clue above has the answer 'opportune'?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, Confused! I have removed the [tag:cryptic-crosswords] tag, as on this site this is only used for complete crosswords... Hopefully my answer below answers your question, but do say if anything is still unclear :)

Answer (score 13):

Let's break it down into smaller chunks:

**Little work**

> '*Work*' in cryptic crosswords commonly clues the word '**[OP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossword_abbreviations)**' as in 'operation'. This (by comparison) is a shorter ('*little*') word.

**left;**

> In nautical terms, the '*left*' side of a ship is known as '**[PORT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_and_starboard)**'.

**a French female**

> The indefinite article '*a*' for words considered feminine ('*female*') in *French* is '**[UNE](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/french-easy-learning/the-indefinite-article-un-une-and-des)**'

**is propitious**

> And finally, this is the definition in the clue - the word '*propitious*' means '**[OPPORTUNE](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/propitious)**'!

Comment: Alternatively, OP can be rot13(bchf), with the same abbreviation.